# SQL Update de uma outra tabela

Tags: jquery, sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-select

Olá, estou tentando fazer um update na tabela produto usando a media dos valores unitários do período de um ano na tabela documentos 
(onde entram as notas ficais) e a instrução q estou usando retorna com erro:

```
UPDATE DimProduto
SET PM = AVG(DimDocumento.Vu)
FROM DimProduto
INNER JOIN
DimDocumento
ON
DimProduto.ProdId = DimDocumento.ProdId
WHERE (DimDocumento.DtCadstr BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateAdd(mm, -12,GetDate()-1),3) AND CONVERT (VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1,3))
```

o erro é:

```
Mensagem 157, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 175
Uma agregação pode não aparecer na lista de conjuntos de uma instrução UPDATE.
```

PM é o campo preço médio da tabela DimProduto e Vu é o campo com o valor unitário da tabela DimDocumento.
Preciso filtrar o período em um ano para ter valores mais atualizados nas comparações.
Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Com função de agregação não vai conseguir mesmo...
Sugiro usar `sub-select` com `exists`.

Exemplo:

```
UPDATE dimproduto
   SET pm = (SELECT AVG(dimdocumento.vu)
                FROM dimdocumento
               WHERE dimproduto.prodid = dimdocumento.prodid
                 AND dimdocumento.dtcadstr BETWEEN
                     convert(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(mm, -12, getdate() - 1), 3) AND
                     convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate() - 1, 3))
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM dimdocumento
                WHERE dimproduto.prodid = dimdocumento.prodid
                  AND dimdocumento.dtcadstr BETWEEN
                     convert(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(mm, -12, getdate() - 1), 3) AND
                     convert(VARCHAR(10), getdate() - 1, 3))
```

Veja rodando [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/00501f/1).

Comment: Vlw Bruno, obrigado pela resposta. Rodou ok.

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Voce pode usar um OUTER APPLY pra resolver isto sem usar subquery

```
        UPDATE A
        SET pm = ISNULL(C.pm, 0)
        FROM dimproduto as A
        OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT AVG(vu) AS pm
                    FROM dimdocumento  AS B
                    WHERE A.prodid = B.prodid
                    ) AS C

        SELECT * 
        FROM dimproduto
```